# Deleting video files using unlink() in PHP 7

Tags: php, file, php-7, unlink

I'm facing a problem with deleting video files from folder using php `unlink()` function , image are deleting but when trying deleting videos it says

```
unlink(file_path) : permission denied.
```

Comment: Are the file permissions on the images the same as on the video's?

Comment: it's permission issue. You can  read, write or execute only a file on which permissions are set to allow this operation. So read a manual about CHMOD or set 777 permissions to your file.

Comment: @jrswgtr , i don't know how to check that in windows, i'm using windows 7 . But images and videos are in same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (running your script as either through CLI or a webserver) need write access to the directory in which the files are located. so access to the file is not enough.

Your image directory would be different and writable for webserver or cli.

```
chmod("your/video/dir/path",0777);
```

try using above code before unlink the video in your script.

Comment: if it is due to permission, then how the images are deleting from the same directory?

Comment: ok..if its in the same directory check the ownership of files and permission on the same...compare it with images,

Comment: thanks, i checked video file it has 'Read Only' checked, i unchecked that and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Looks like you are using Windows. Unfortunately, my answer is for Unix-like operating systems (so Linux, MacOS). You could try installing Bash extension for Win8+, but still I'm not sure if this would work. However, I'm keeping my answer in case of anyone with similar problem is looking here for an answer.

Changing permissions through PHP might work in some cases, but not always, because if you don't have permissions to delete the file you might also not have permissions to change them.

The best solution is to create a directory where you will keep files to which PHP will have full access. Let's call it `dirname`. Once you have created a directory, change its owner and group to the one corresponding to your web server user's name (if you're using Apache, it's "www-data"), for example: `chown www-data:www-data dirname`.

Once you've done that, change folder's permissions. My suggestion is `744`, it will assure that user who owns it will have all permissions, and everyone else will be able only to read it. To do that, execute the following command: `chmod -R 777 dirname`.

Now you should be able to do anything you want with the files in given directory directly from PHP.